# Get IStorage from ComTypes.STGMEDIUM in C++

Tags: c++, .net, winapi, visual-c++

I got a [ComTypes.STGMEDIUM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7hfcbw59%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) object and I want to get its IStorage. From [STGMEDIUM struct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683812%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you can get it with the help of the pstg member. The [ComTypes.STGMEDIUM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7hfcbw59%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) class is missing such an member.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's there, the union was flattened to a simple single field of type IntPtr.  You can just cast it:

```
#include <windows.h>

using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;

    //...
    ComTypes::STGMEDIUM foo;
    IStorage* pStore = (IStorage*)foo.unionmember.ToPointer();
```

Or you could marshal the entire structure if you prefer:

```
::STGMEDIUM native;
Marshal::StructureToPtr(foo, IntPtr(&native), false);
IStorage* pStore = native.pstg;
```